# Как узнать расположение bin папки для mariadb в ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mariadb

Собственно в этом и есть вопрос. bin папка для mariadb вообще существует? Есть папка с данными и по умолчанию она находится в usr/lib/mysql как я понял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в убунту папка бин находится в /bin, /usr/bin или /usr/local/bin. и они общие для всех приложений в системе. в папке /usr/lib/mysql лежат плагины.

посмотреть где лежат файлы сервера можно командой

```
dpkg-query --listfiles mariadb-server-core-10.5
dpkg-query --listfiles mariadb-server-10.5
```

```
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/innochecksum
/usr/bin/mariadb-install-db
/usr/bin/mariadb-upgrade
/usr/bin/my_print_defaults
/usr/bin/resolveip
/usr/sbin
/usr/sbin/mariadbd
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/mariadb-server-core-10.5
/usr/share/doc/mariadb-server-core-10.5/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/mariadb-server-core-10.5/copyright
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/mariadb-server-core-10.5
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/innochecksum.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/my_print_defaults.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_install_db.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_upgrade.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/resolveip.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man8
/usr/share/man/man8/mysqld.8.gz
/usr/share/mysql
/usr/share/mysql/charsets
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/README
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/armscii8.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/ascii.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1250.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1251.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1256.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1257.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp850.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp852.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp866.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/dec8.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/geostd8.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/greek.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/hebrew.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/hp8.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/keybcs2.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8r.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8u.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin1.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin2.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin5.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin7.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/macce.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/macroman.xml
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/swe7.xml
/usr/share/mysql/czech
/usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/danish
/usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/dutch
/usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/english
/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/estonian
/usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/fill_help_tables.sql
/usr/share/mysql/french
/usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/german
/usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/greek
/usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/hindi
/usr/share/mysql/hindi/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/hungarian
/usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/italian
/usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/japanese
/usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/korean
/usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/maria_add_gis_sp_bootstrap.sql
/usr/share/mysql/mysql_performance_tables.sql
/usr/share/mysql/mysql_system_tables.sql
/usr/share/mysql/mysql_system_tables_data.sql
/usr/share/mysql/mysql_test_data_timezone.sql
/usr/share/mysql/mysql_test_db.sql
/usr/share/mysql/norwegian
/usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny
/usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/polish
/usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/portuguese
/usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/romanian
/usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/russian
/usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/serbian
/usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/slovak
/usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/spanish
/usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/swedish
/usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys
/usr/share/mysql/ukrainian
/usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys
/usr/bin/mysql_install_db
/usr/bin/mysql_upgrade
/usr/sbin/mysqld
/usr/share/man/man1/mariadb-install-db.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mariadb-upgrade.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/mariadbd.8.gz

/.
/etc
/etc/apparmor.d
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mariadbd
/etc/init.d
/etc/init.d/mariadb
/etc/logcheck
/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.paranoid
/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.paranoid/mariadb-server-10_5
/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server
/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server/mariadb-server-10_5
/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.workstation
/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.workstation/mariadb-server-10_5
/etc/logrotate.d
/etc/logrotate.d/mariadb
/etc/mysql
/etc/mysql/debian-start
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysqld_safe.cnf
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
/etc/security
/etc/security/user_map.conf
/lib
/lib/systemd
/lib/systemd/system
/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service
/lib/systemd/system/mariadb@.service
/lib/systemd/system/mariadb@bootstrap.service.d
/lib/systemd/system/mariadb@bootstrap.service.d/use_galera_new_cluster.conf
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_user_map.so
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/aria_chk
/usr/bin/aria_dump_log
/usr/bin/aria_ftdump
/usr/bin/aria_pack
/usr/bin/aria_read_log
/usr/bin/galera_new_cluster
/usr/bin/galera_recovery
/usr/bin/mariadb-binlog
/usr/bin/mariadb-convert-table-format
/usr/bin/mariadb-hotcopy
/usr/bin/mariadb-plugin
/usr/bin/mariadb-secure-installation
/usr/bin/mariadb-service-convert
/usr/bin/mariadb-setpermission
/usr/bin/mariadb-tzinfo-to-sql
/usr/bin/mariadbd-multi
/usr/bin/mariadbd-safe
/usr/bin/mariadbd-safe-helper
/usr/bin/msql2mysql
/usr/bin/myisam_ftdump
/usr/bin/myisamchk
/usr/bin/myisamlog
/usr/bin/myisampack
/usr/bin/perror
/usr/bin/replace
/usr/bin/resolve_stack_dump
/usr/bin/wsrep_sst_common
/usr/bin/wsrep_sst_mariabackup
/usr/bin/wsrep_sst_mysqldump
/usr/bin/wsrep_sst_rsync
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/mysql
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/auth_ed25519.so
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/auth_pam.so
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/auth_pam_tool_dir
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/auth_pam_tool_dir/auth_pam_tool
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/auth_pam_v1.so
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/disks.so
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/file_key_management.so
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_archive.so
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_blackhole.so
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_federated.so
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_federatedx.so
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_sphinx.so
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/handlersocket.so
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/locales.so
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/metadata_lock_info.so
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/query_cache_info.so
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/query_response_time.so
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/server_audit.so
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/simple_password_check.so
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/sql_errlog.so
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/type_mysql_json.so
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/wsrep_info.so
/usr/share
/usr/share/apport
/usr/share/apport/package-hooks
/usr/share/apport/package-hooks/source_mariadb-10.5.py
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/mariadb-server-10.5
/usr/share/doc/mariadb-server-10.5/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/mariadb-server-10.5/README.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/mariadb-server-10.5/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/mariadb-server-10.5/copyright
/usr/share/doc/mariadb-server-10.5/mariadbd.sym.gz
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/mariadb-server-10.5
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/aria_chk.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/aria_dump_log.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/aria_ftdump.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/aria_pack.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/aria_read_log.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/galera_new_cluster.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/galera_recovery.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mariadb-service-convert.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/msql2mysql.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/myisam_ftdump.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/myisamchk.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/myisamlog.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/myisampack.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_convert_table_format.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_plugin.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_secure_installation.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_setpermission.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_tzinfo_to_sql.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlbinlog.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqld_multi.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqld_safe.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqld_safe_helper.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlhotcopy.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perror.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/replace.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/resolve_stack_dump.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/wsrep_sst_common.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/wsrep_sst_mariabackup.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/wsrep_sst_mysqldump.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/wsrep_sst_rsync.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/wsrep_sst_rsync_wan.1.gz
/usr/share/mysql
/usr/share/mysql/debian-start.inc.sh
/usr/share/mysql/echo_stderr
/usr/share/mysql/errmsg-utf8.txt
/usr/share/mysql/wsrep.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/wsrep_notify
/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service
/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service
/usr/bin/mysql_convert_table_format
/usr/bin/mysql_plugin
/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
/usr/bin/mysql_setpermission
/usr/bin/mysql_tzinfo_to_sql
/usr/bin/mysqlbinlog
/usr/bin/mysqld_multi
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe_helper
/usr/bin/mysqlhotcopy
/usr/bin/wsrep_sst_rsync_wan
/usr/share/man/man1/mariadb-binlog.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mariadb-convert-table-format.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mariadb-hotcopy.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mariadb-plugin.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mariadb-secure-installation.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mariadb-setpermission.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mariadb-tzinfo-to-sql.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mariadbd-multi.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mariadbd-safe-helper.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mariadbd-safe.1.gz
```